# What are natural retro-reflectors?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, reflection

Recently I was on an airplane on a sunny day.  The sun was shining on the other side of the plane and noticed a bright patch on the ground following beside us. Eventually I noticed a dark centre to this bright patch, the plane's shadow, which became more distant as the plane descended. When the plane flew over a city road signs in this bright patch lit up brightly because of their retro-reflective paint.

My question is, what was acting as a retro-reflector to produce this bright patch when it wasn't passing over a road sign? When flying over water the bright patch disappeared, or was very faint.  I could see it over forests, more clearly over cut grain fields and, at least faintly over a wide range of terrain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a version of [the glory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glory_(optical_phenomenon)), or more likely  [heiligenschein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heiligenschein), due to spherical droplets of water in the air or dew on the ground.